# Comparison of excel files, cell by cell

Tags: performance, excel, vbscript

below is the code that i created as a POC towards an implementation for 2 excel file comparison (cell by cell)

This was just to test the logic, which works as expected, however i found out that for big data (hundreds of rows and columns) this approach using excel object is very time consuming. Approx time taken for comparing 130 rows and 248 columns was about 10 mins.

Is there any way that i can optimize this

Note: " the code is at basic level" kindly answer towards optimization only

The Code is as below

```
Dim a()
Dim b()
x = 0
file1 = InputBox("Enter the first file")
file2 = InputBox("enter the second file")

'create FSO and check if the file exist
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 if (fso.fileExists(file1)) and (fso.fileExists(file2)) then
  MsgBox "The file exists"
Else
  MsgBox "The file doesn't exists"
  ErrCount = 1
End if

if Errcount <> 1 then 
 'Create excel object for both the files and compare
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 'Iterate from worksheets for both the file
  Set objFile1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(file1)
  objFile1Count = objFile1.Worksheets.count

  Set objFile2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(file2)
  objFile2Count = objFile2.Worksheets.count
 End if

'sheet should be same
 if objFile1Count <> objFile2Count then
   ErrCount = 1
 End if
' Loop through the sheets
  if ErrCount <> 1 then
      For cnt = 1 to objFile1.Sheets.count
        Set file1Sheet = objFile1.Sheets(cnt)
        Set file2Sheet = objFile2.Sheets(cnt)
        'Check the sheet name
        if file1Sheet.Name <> file2Sheet.Name then
          ErrCount = 1
          Exit For
        Else
          'File 1
          file1RC = file1Sheet.usedrange.rows.count
          file1CC = file1Sheet.usedrange.columns.count
          'File 2
          file2RC = file2Sheet.usedrange.columns.count
          file2CC = file2Sheet.usedrange.columns.count

          'Iterate file
            For i = 2 to file1RC
              For j = 1 to file1CC
                      ReDim Preserve a(x)
                      ReDim Preserve b(x)
                      a(x) = Trim(file1Sheet.Rows(i).columns(j).value)
                      b(x) = Trim(file2Sheet.Rows(i).columns(j).value)
                      file2getRC = i &"," &j 
                      file1getRC = i &"," &j

                      'Check compare and add color
                       File1Val = a(x)
                       File2Val = b(x)

                       if File1Val = File2Val then
                          'do nothing as the values matches
                       Else
                          RNC = split(file1getRC, ",")
                          Col = RNC(1)
                          Row = RNC(0)
                          Col = CInt(Col)

                          ty = file1Sheet.Rows(Row).Cells(1, Col).value
                          file1Sheet.Rows(Row).Cells(1, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                          file2Sheet.Rows(Row).Cells(1, Col).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                          objFile1.Save
                          objFile2.Save
                       End if 
                      x=x+1
              Next
            Next
           End if
        Next
  MsgBox "it works"
Else
  MsgBox "No file added or cancelled" 
    End if
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with lot of trials - I found a small workaround. However its not at all optimal as you would be looking for in an answer.

I tried using the following code for comparison and highlighting.

```
For Each Cell In file2Sheet.UsedRange
    If Cell.Formula <> file1Sheet.Range(Cell.Address).Formula Then
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        file1Sheet.Range(Cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    End If
Next
```

This reduced the time than my initial approach (130x248 cells = about 9 mins) to about 1 min.
This may seem a significant time saving but extrapolating this time to a database size with upwards of 7000 rows would still be too much.

The catch is that this same piece of code when used with macro works extremely fast (complete data under 40 seconds) but when used in VbScript or some tool like QTP/Test Complete takes before mentioned higher time

If anyone can take it ahead from here - Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You only ask about performance, but I want to point out anyway that there is a small error in the definition of `file2RC`: you used `column` instead of `row`.

Now, let me get to the performance part. The thing making your code slow is that accesses to worksheets are expensive. Accordingly, they should be reduced to a minimum.

Currently, you access each cell individually. A better approach is to load all on the same sheet in one go. You can do this by assigning the `Value` property, or better the `Value2` property (`Value` causes problems with fields formatted as dates.), of the used range to a `Variant` variable. After that, the variable contains a two-dimensional array consisting of the values in the range.

By comparing the values in corresponding arrays, you only need to access each sheet once to load the data and then for each time you find an error, in order to change the color.

Comment: Hi @M.Doerner, Thank you for your answer. However, I think i might have failed to understand the solution properly - did you mean i should try something like this -

            `newFile1V = file1Sheet.usedrange.Value`

            `newFile2V = file2Sheet.usedrange.Value`

and to compare something like this where i,j corresponds to row and column iteration

        `newFile1V(i,j) = newFile2V(i,j)`

Comment: That is basically my suggestion. However, I would use `Value2`, which is faster and avoids strange behavior for fields formatted as currency or date.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with      `value 2` . however, with prior suggestion wasn't much help as it marginally improved the time. Maybe i did something wrong ?

Comment: I used    `value2`  but it didn't help as the time taken was same as     `value`. am i doing something wrong or any more ideas ?